# SQL 2008 BULK INSERT with spanish charcters

Tags: sql-server-2008, internationalization, bulkinsert

I'm using SQL BULK insert from a CSV file with some spanish names like `Zuñiga`. The CSV file in UTF-8 format (As far as I know).

These show up in the table in one of these two formats:
For NVARCHAR - `Zu├▒iga`
for VARCHAR - `ZuÃ±iga`

The command I'm using is

```
BULK INSERT temp_table FROM '<some CSV file>' WITH (CODEPAGE = 'RAW',
DATAFILETYPE = 'char', FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',FIRSTROW = 2)
```

I was aslo testing all variations of `CODEPAGE` and `DATAFILETYPE` with similar results

**UPDATE**
Saved the CSV (using notepad save-as) as unicode and that fixed the problem. But I need some kind of automatic solution. I prefere to fix the SQL to handle it, and not to preptocess the CSV

Comment: I ended up converting the CSV to Unicode before using the BULK INSERT

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `codepage="RAW"`, you need to specify the proper code page so that the file reader understands the content of the file. If the file is trully UTF-8 then you should set the code page to 65001.

Comment: the MSDN page (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) explicitly states code page 65001 is not supported with 2008 R2
"SQL Server does not support code page 65001 (UTF-8 encoding)."

Comment: @Ron Harlev: I know: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/370419/bulk-insert-and-bcp-does-not-recognize-codepage-65001 That's what is going to make this problem of importing an UTF-8 file even more interesting...